# the meaning of the following assembly code, help

Tags: assembly, pic, u-boot

The following piece of code is from u-boot:

```
        /* Initialize GOT pointer.
        ** Global symbols can't be resolved before this is done, and as such we can't
        ** use any global symbols in this code.  We use the bal/ move xxx,ra combination to access
        ** data in a PC relative manner to avoid this.  This code will correctly set the
        ** gp regardless of whether the code has already been relocated or not.                                                          
        ** This code determines the current gp by computing the link time (gp - pc)                                                      
        ** and adding this to the current pc.                                                                                            
        ** runtime_gp = runtime_pc + (linktime_gp - linktime_pc)                                                                         
        ** U-boot is running from the address it is linked at at this time, so this                                                      
        ** general case code is not strictly necessary here.                                                                             
        */                                                                                                                               

/*Branch and link to get current PC in ra */                                                                                     
        bal     1f                                                                                                     
        nop                                                                                               
        .extern _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_                                            
        .word   _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_  /* This contains the linked address of the GOT */                                                 
        /* The ra register now contains the runtime address of the above memory location */                                              

        .word   . - 4                  /* This contains the link time address of the previous word,                                      
                                        which is also what the link time expected PC value is */                                         
1:                                                                                                
        move    gp, ra    /* Move current PC into gp register */                                                                         
        lw      a5, 0(ra) /* Load linked address of the GOT into a5 */                                                                   
        lw      a6, 4(ra) /* Load the link time address of the GOT storage location into a6 */                                           
        sub     a5, a6    /* Subtract a6 from t1. */                                                                                     
        /* a5 now contains the difference between the link-time GOT table address and the link time expected PC */                       

        /* Add this difference to the current PC (copied into gp above) so that gp now has the current runtime                           
        ** GOT table address */                                                                                                          
        daddu   gp, a5  # calculate current location of offset table
```

I don't understand 3 directive above:

```
.extern _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
.word _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ //what the meaning after declaring it as a external symbol?
.word . -4  //and also this one?
```

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.extern _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
```

The symbol is described outside of this compilation unit.  Resolve it at link time.

```
.word _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
```

Allocate a word worth of memory and place the address of the symbol at this location

```
.word . - 4
```

Take the current location, `.`, subtract 4 and place that value in a word of memory.  Similar to the previous code except the value being placed at this location is being computed.

Here is a [link](http://sources.redhat.com/binutils/docs-2.12/as.info/Pseudo-Ops.html#Pseudo%20Ops) with a list of many of the assembler directives.

Comment: .word expression's expression is just the content of the word. thanks

Comment: and another question: who is resiponsible for the generation of symbol _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_?

Comment: You should be able to find that symbol in some other source file.  During the linking of the final binary that symbol will be resolved.  If it cannot be found you will get a linker error.  Use something like `grep` to find that string in the code base.

Comment: i check all the object file, no this symbol is found. so i guess the linker produce this symbol.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.  I have done very little with PIC.  However a quick search uncovers the symbol: http://www.infosecwriters.com/text_resources/pdf/GOT_Hijack.pdf.  It is created and populated during link time.  Thanks for exposing me to this.  Very interesting!